# Flexible size multi-dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, row

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array which will store 'customer' information, where each row will be for a customer, and the columns store information about the customer. For instance, some columns may be: Name, PhoneNo, Address, PostCode, ID. I know beforehand the number of required columns. However, I do not know how many rows are required.

This poses a problem as, to declare such an Array one must specify the number of rows in addition to the columns. Is there a way to declare such an array with perhaps a flexible-sized number of rows, or is there a similar type of data collection that would allow me to do so?

Comment: Are you referring to interacting with a database? Otherwise, it sounds like you need a `List` of `Customer` objects.

Comment: Yes I am referring to a similar concept used in databases, however I am trying to learn how to apply it within a Java application.

Comment: You should use a `vector` or an `ArrayList`

Comment: @MarounMaroun `Vector` is old hat now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the ArrayList class. This will adjust as necessary. To create, just use:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

customers.add(new Customer(...)); //to add
customers.get(index); // to retrieve
```

Of course, this assumes you have a Customer object, which I would recommend to store each attribute, rather than an array of arrays.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, strangely it did not occur to me to create a customer object. Oh well, I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an ArrayList. You can just append data if needed.